# Java spring based webapp vs pure javascript webapp

Tags: java, javascript, spring, web-applications

I have two options infront of me for web development.

Can you guys share your views on which projects suits for each of the paths:

**path 1:**  java + spring on server side and javascript/html on front end.

**path 2:**  pure javascript/Html based webapp.

Below is my project basic functionality. Can you guys share your views on which path is better and why.

The basic functionality of the app is when user enters some data in the app i will hit 4 or 5 web services and get json data back and display on front end.

I want to mention that hitting the webservices is not straight forward. I need to do some complex normalizations before calling the webservices and i also have to do some preprocessing on json before sending it to front end. Soon or latter i believe we have to save user preferences in the app.

Now my question which technology to use. Given the above specifications is it good to go with java and spring on server side and HTML + javascript on front end or pure Javascript/HTML based webapp.

I am looking for inputs like preformance comparisions, code maintainence constraints etc. Also if the answer is javacript/html then please let me know if any libraries like bootstrap or other mvc that is better for this case.

Thanks

Comment: I don't find javascript/html very maintainable. For that reason alone, I would use java (+ insert framework) for this in the back end.

Comment: Do you need some sort of security layer? Login? Authentication and Authorization?

Comment: I dont need authentication.

Comment: I'm very confused with this question, so your app doesn't need any backend storage at all? What's going to be happening on the backend? If not much than you really don't need Spring at all.

Comment: OK. Right now from the front end we make ajax calls and spring controller listens to the url and calls respective methods, do some stuff and returns back view.

Comment: I think, that he's gonna do there some validation/formatting of those JSONs...

Answer (score 2):

If this project is small with small data, than use what you know better, don't care the technology, because not much importance since is small. Learning a spring or learning javascript isn't an 1h task.

The javascript is easy and everybody knows, easy to find cheap developer.
A pure javascript project has no deploy, hosting issues ( most of free hosting server doesn't allow Java)

if you go to server side + client side:
Ofc PHP should be the cheapest solution for developing and hosting, not java based technologies. Again it depends on developer knowledge.

If you go with any Java based MVC solution like, Spring, Struts, GWT is again what you / your developer knows, for me personally is almost the same. Choosing one of this, is like a religion. Endless comparation can be written, choose one, which you are confortable, plenty of code samples.

If the project middle, big size or special needs ( banking stuff) than no PHP, just Java, or ASP.net + C# s the way I would go.

Depends on buget allocated: pure javascript should be cheaper.

Comment: Budget is not constraint. I am good at both java and javascript. project is not a small one. There will be some heavy traffice once it goes live.

Comment: @javaMan  I don't believe on it, but there is the  `Node.js`, as I have heard used for serverside Javascript! - like on Twitter. GWT has a long app startup, you can see when the gmail is loading first time in browser. Heavy trafic => not PHP,  I suggest than Java, but still a religion which one framework, what you like it, what you know it

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you to use `Spring 3 MVC`. This will provide you nice `MVC` structure, so any further changes in model/view/controller will be independent on the rest of your solution. The next thing is, that you can easily integrate any other framework and technologie (e.g. hibernate), that will ease your work and speed up the development. And last but not least - if the user can't see the logic, that's behind his webpage and get's only formated `html`, because all the logic is in the controller on the server side, your app will be much more secured..